# How to load complete JSON scene or multi parts model into three.js ( using blender to export )

Tags: json, three.js, blender, 3d-modelling

I'm trying to load a simple car model that is separated into *tires*, *body* and *windows* into **three.js**, I use **Blender** to export as `.json` but when I use the **JSONloader** it only loads the body.

So then I try to export it as scene, but when I use the **JSONloader** nothing show up in the scene.

So I have two questions:

1. What is the proper way to export and load a multi part model from Blender JSON?
2. How do I load a JSON scene exported from Blender into three.js?

Following @larsenhupin suggestion heres my try with objectloader, however the scene doesn't show

```
//LOAD A JSON SCENE

var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

loader.load(
    // resource URL
    "models/stockcarb.json"

    // pass the loaded data to the onLoad function.
//Here it is assumed to be an object
    function ( obj ) {
        //add the loaded object to the scene
        scene.add( obj );
    },

    // Function called when download progresses
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
    },

    // Function called when download errors
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.error( 'An error happened' );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when I export a **scene** from Blender it works using the `ObjectLoader();` instead of the `JSONLoader();`.

https://threejs.org/docs/api/loaders/ObjectLoader.html

Do you plan to use animations ? I ask because I've never been able to use animations with the ObjectLoader, it can works but it never happened for me.

Comment: Thanks gonna give a try and tell my results, I thought ObjectLoader(); was for .obj models.

As right now I don't need animation, buy I know eventually will need them.

Comment: I tried the ObjectLoader but the model is not showing, I'm getting this errors from the console. 

`JSONLoader.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`
`ObjectLoader.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`
`index.html:215 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Above in my question I paste how I tried to load the scene